# Does command line arguments and File I/O operation consume CPU Time potentially?

Tags: command-line, process, cpu, io

According to the definition of the **CPU Time**:

> CPU time (or CPU Execution time) is the time between the start and the end of execution of a given program. This time accounts for the time CPU is computing the given program, including operating system routines executed on the program’s behalf, and it does not include the time waiting for I/O and running other programs.

While measuring CPU Time for a process, is the time involved in operations like establishing and closing of the I/O streams (for command line arguments and file) included in the CPU Time?

Answer (score 0):

Yes (for sane implementations and reasonable definitions)

Obviously if you have a command like `cat /etc/passwd` then the process will do the calls to `open(2)` to open the file.

Slightly less obviously if you have a command like `cat < /etc/passwd` the cost of opening the file will also be changed to that process, at least for typical shell implementations. The shell will process that command as follows.

1. It will see that `cat` is not a builtin command. Therefore it will create a new process to run it. Traditionally this would be using the fork(2) system call, but can be vfork or clone or spawn system calls these days depending on the system.
2. The original process will call some version of the wait system call as the command didn't end in an `&`.
3. The new process is still running the shell. It will call `open` to open the file and will arrange for the opened file to be on file descriptor 0. There are at least a couple of ways it can do that, but the point is that this new process is calling open.
4. The new process then transforms itself into `cat` using some version of the `exec` system call.
5. Eventually `cat` will exit, and the original shell will return from its `wait` call.

So the new process will have the cost of setting up the I/O stream in this case as well. Of course the costs of setting up the I/O are typically small compared to actually doing the I/O.

For the close, things are a little more complicated. The runtime associated with the program will usually flush any buffers and close open files. The time to do this is accounted against the process. When a process exits any remaining open files are closed. The cost of doing this might or might not be accounted to the process.

If you have something like FUSE where another process is providing the file system then the time spent in the other process to do the open will be charged to that process rather than the process making the open call.